# Proving for $w \in \Bbb C$ with modulus $1$ and argument $2 \theta$ that $\frac{w-1}{w+1}=i\tan \theta$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> The complex number w has modulus $1$ and argument 2$\theta$ radians. Show that
>   $$\frac{w-1}{w+1}=i\tan \theta.$$

Attempted solution:

I just assumed that $w=1(\cos 2\theta +i \sin 2\theta)$
and used an expression $$Arg(w)=2\theta.$$
Then 
$$w=\tan(2\theta).$$
Then what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Like you've observed, the conditions on $w$ give that $$w = e^{2 i \theta}.$$ Instead of expanding it using Euler's formula, we can substitute directly into the l.h.s. of the identity:
$$\frac{w - 1}{w + 1} = \frac{e^{2i \theta} - 1}{e^{2i \theta} + 1}.$$
Now, we can rewrite this as
$$\frac{e^{i \theta} - e^{-i \theta}}{e^{i \theta} + e^{i \theta}}.$$